# Android - How can I get Application Icon if it isn't installed?

Tags: java, android

If I have package name of an application how can i acquire this Application Icon if this app isn't installed

I've only found solutions for when the application is installed on this device using `PackageManager` and all that but in this case packageManager doesn't work

We've used market API but it doesn't get Icons for new applications over android 2.2

Answer (score 2):

> If I have package name of an application how can i acquire this Application Icon if this app isn't installed

Contact the developers and ask for a copy of their icon, along with a license to use that icon. Or, see if they have a "press kit" on their Web site that you could use.